# Spring Roo 2.0.0.RC1 doesn't know its own version number

Tags: spring, spring-roo

When I start `roo.sh`, the command logs a lot of error about the version of libraries and the Roo version:

```
$ /opt/apps/ggg/spring-roo-2.0.0.RC1/bin/roo.sh
Auto-deploy install: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Bundle symbolic name and version are not unique: com.github.antlrjavaparser.antlr-java-parser:1.0.15
Auto-deploy install: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Bundle symbolic name and version are not unique: org.apache.commons.codec:1.8.0
Auto-deploy install: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Bundle symbolic name and version are not unique: org.apache.commons.io:2.4.0
Auto-deploy install: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Bundle symbolic name and version are not unique: org.apache.commons.lang3:3.1.0
Auto-deploy install: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Bundle symbolic name and version are not unique: org.fusesource.jansi:1.6.0
Auto-deploy install: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Bundle symbolic name and version are not unique: org.jsoup:1.9.1
Auto-deploy install: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Bundle symbolic name and version are not unique: org.apache.aries.subsystem.api:2.0.8
Auto-deploy install: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Bundle symbolic name and version are not unique: org.apache.aries.subsystem.core:2.0.8
Auto-deploy install: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Bundle symbolic name and version are not unique: org.apache.aries.util:1.1.1
```

... *More "Auto-deploy" warnings and finally* ...

```
            _                               
 ___ _ __  _ __(_)_ __   __ _   _ __ ___   ___  
/ __| '_ \| '__| | '_ \ / _` | | '__/ _ \ / _ \ 
\__ \ |_) | |  | | | | | (_| | | | | (_) | (_) |
|___/ .__/|_|  |_|_| |_|\__, | |_|  \___/ \___/ 
    |_|                 |___/    UNKNOWN VERSION

Welcome to Spring Roo. For assistance press TAB or type "hint" then hit ENTER.
roo>
```

And if I create a project, the Spring Roo's version in the `pom.xml` file created is `UNKNOWN VERSION`:

```
  <properties>
    <roo.version>UNKNOWN VERSION</roo.version>
```

Then, if I fix the file setting the `2.0.0 RC1` version, when I start again the Roo console, it shows me:

```
...
Auto-deploy install: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Bundle symbolic name and version are not unique: org.springframework.roo.wrapping.snakeyaml:1.15.1
Auto-deploy install: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Bundle symbolic name and version are not unique: slf4j.api:1.7.12
Auto-deploy install: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Bundle symbolic name and version are not unique: slf4j.jdk14:1.7.12
                _                               
 ___ _ __  _ __(_)_ __   __ _   _ __ ___   ___  
/ __| '_ \| '__| | '_ \ / _` | | '__/ _ \ / _ \ 
\__ \ |_) | |  | | | | | (_| | | | | (_) | (_) |
|___/ .__/|_|  |_|_| |_|\__, | |_|  \___/ \___/ 
    |_|                 |___/    UNKNOWN VERSION

Welcome to Spring Roo. For assistance press TAB or type "hint" then hit ENTER.
WARNING: You are using Spring Roo UNKNOWN VERSION, but project was generated using Spring Roo 2.0.0 RC1.
If you continue with the execution your project might suffer some changes.
Do you want to continue opening Spring Roo Shell?(YES/No)
```

How can I fix this issue with the version? Is there a file where I can setup the version number?

Comment: are you opening a clean distribution of Spring Roo downloaded from http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/? Regards,

Comment: Yes, I downloaded from there. Also I have Ubuntu 14.04 x64 and Java Oracle 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: Spring Roo uses the name of the folder where is contained to known its own version. After rename the folder `/opt/apps/ggg/roo` to `/opt/apps/ggg/spring-roo-2.0.0.RC1` worked as expected.

I known that the original name in the distribution file downloaded from http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/ was `spring-roo-2.0.0.RC1` (I renamed it when I uncompressed the zip into `/opt/apps/ggg`), but I never thought that Spring used the folder name to known the version, and to be honest, I never saw a behavior like this, but renaming the folder name solve the problem.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: humm ... looking into the question, I see that I posted the path as `/opt/apps/ggg/spring-roo-2.0.0.RC1` instance of the real path in my computer `/opt/apps/ggg/roo`, sorry, I did that because testing other problems I reported, I used more than one unzipped Roo installations.

Answer (score 1):

I've saw that you're executing the `roo.sh` script in the following folder:

`/opt/apps/ggg`

Do you have admin permissions in that folder? Could you try to execute the `roo.sh` script inside `~/apps/ggg` folder?

Let me know if that helps you.

Regards

Comment: Hello @jcgarcia. Yes, I can read, write and execute files inside the `ggg` folder. I executed the `roo.sh` file and I got the same errors, but, with an extra error that I don't see when I execute the script in other folders: `The module for the file '/opt/apps/ggg/groovy-2.4.7/src/src/main/groovy/lang/ClosureException.java' could not be located`, maybe because I have a groovy version installed at `/opt/apps/ggg/groovy-2.4.7`.

Comment: Of course! Remember that the Spring Roo shell must be opened only in empty folders or in folders that contains an existing Spring Roo project. If you execute the `roo.sh` script in a folder that contains some folder without correct Spring Roo project structure multiple errors will appear. Try to execute it again in an empty folder and let me know if that works for you. Regards